# Is it possible to add an href attribute to autocomplete function by materialize?

Tags: jquery, materialize

Once clicked the autocompleted `<li>` that is generated after introducing words to be redirected to anywhere. I guess it might be something like this:

```
"Apple": {
    id: 1,
    text: 'Apple Inc',
    image: null,
    href: 'http://google.es',
},
```

But of course it doesn't work with the href line :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one option in `.autocomplete()` that is,

```
onAutocomplete: function(val) {
      // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
},
```

So whatever you have written inside `onAutocomplete:` option, that will get executed after you have selected a value from autocomplete input. In your case you want to open a specified URL, so you can use `window.open()` to achieve that.

I have created a working `jsfiddle` take a look at it.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/Tirth_Patel/bcct9nfn/

***Example***

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">

        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Autocomplete</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
          "Apple": null,
          "Google": null,
          "Microsoft": null,
        },

        onAutocomplete: function(val) {

           // Callback function when value is autcompleted.

           // Grabbing input after autocomplete is done
           var value = $('input.autocomplete').val();

           if(value == "Apple"){
               var link = window.open('http://www.apple.com', '_blank');
               link.location;

           } else if(value == "Google"){
               var link = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
               link.location;

           } else {
               var link = window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', '_blank');
               link.location;
           }

        },

    });
});
```

**EDIT**

To open `Different URLs` on `Different autocomplete` then grab the value of `autocomplete input` after autocomplete is done and check the value with `if..else` and open different URLs for different autocomplete.

Comment: It will open the same url in all the autocomplete values or can I set a different one to each other?

Comment: If you want to open  different URLs on different autocomplete then you can just grab the value of autocomplete input after autocomplete is finished and check the value with if..else and open your different desired URLs for each autocomplete. I've updated my code and jsfiddle, take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I need :-)